# How to fetch the only those qty which exist in 3 continuous size?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table ILE on which there are few items and every items have more than 6 sizes. i need to get the sum of qty size wise only which has 3 continuous sizes.
Ex:

ILE TABLE

```
Item    Size    Qty
A1        80      2
A1      85  4
A1      90  5
A1      100 7
A1      80  3
A1      90  4
A2      80  4
A2      90  3
A2      95  6
A2      95  7
```

Result Required only of 3 Continuous size's records

```
A1  80  5
A1  85  4
A1  90  9
A1  100 7
```

Comment: what is your dbms name

Answer (score 0):

You may try using lag function() as your dbms is MSSQL

```
with testcte as
(
select *, case when size=size-lag(size,1,0) over(partition by item order by size) then 5 else
size-lag(size,1,0) over(partition by item order by size) end as d
from
(
select item,size,sum(qty) as q from
tablename
group by item,size
)x
)

select * from testcte a where exists (select 1 from testcte b where a.item=b.item having count(distinct case when d=5 then 1 end)=3)
```

Comment: _3 continuous sizes_?

Comment: that's the point where I stuck, from his sample data it seemed to me that he needs this solution but no sure :( @jarlh

Comment: yes 3 continuous sizes...means in DB there are sizes like 75, 80, 85, 90, 95,100, 105,110,115, and i need sum(quantity) of only those values which have at least 3 continuous size (75,80,85 or 80,85,90 or 85,90,95
i dont need data of such sizes... 75,80, 90 or 80,90, 100 like that

Comment: @MukeshUniyal, what is your dbms name

Comment: Microsoft Sql server

Answer (score 0):

Use a *common table expression* that returns only items with numeric sizes.

Have a sub-query that checks if size - 5 and size + 5 also exists for an item. For such an item, return all rows.

```
with iles as
(
    select * from ile
    where ISNUMERIC(size) > 0
)
select * from iles
where item in
    (select item from iles i1
     where exists (select 1 from iles i2
                   where i2.item = i1.item and i2.size = i1.size - 5)
       and exists (select 1 from iles i3
                   where i3.item = i1.item and i3.size = i1.size + 5))
```

Comment: if for A2 there is another size 100 then will it work?

Comment: sorry but there is one more issue in ILE there are other sizes as well (Like sky,blue etc) but i want to skip those sizes from the output..

Comment: Add those types to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: I don't want data to fetch the sizes which are non numeric...Mr Jarlh Please help..

Comment: Not at all, even if the same item has 3 continuous sizes (numerical ones)?

Comment: Added that condition to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need ?

```
DECLARE 
    @t  TABLE (Item VARCHAR(10), Size INT, Qty INT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('A1',80,2),
('A1',85,4),
('A1',90,5),
('A1',100,7),
('A1',80,3),
('A1',90,4),
('A2',80,4),
('A2',90,3),
('A2',95,6),
('A2',95,7)

SELECT 
    Item
,   Size
,   Qty
FROM (

    SELECT *
    ,   COUNT(Item) OVER(PARTITION BY Item) CNT 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            Item
        ,   Size
        ,   cnt Qty
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            ,   SUM(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY Item, Size) cnt
            FROM @t
        ) D
        GROUP BY Item, Size, cnt
    ) C 
) E 
WHERE CNT = 4
```